# Loading 100 data every time in Recycler view in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, loader

I show 100 data in Recycler view like when I scroll down recycler view it loads the data, first time it loads all 100 data in recycler view but second time when I open Recycler view scroll stops at 50th values and it shows only 50 values so remaining values are not loaded, kindly help me to solve this issue in android.

Comment: Try to put breakpoints to validate data

Comment: post some code too.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the list you are giving to recyclerview, wheather it contains all records or not. Add some breakpoint to validate it.
And also share the code for more efficient answers.